# How can I get the original pipeline object when using ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm building a Cmdlet in C#.

When binding parameters using `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=true`, I often would like to pass the original pipeline object from which the properties were bound back into the pipeline. How can I get a reference to this original object?

So if this is my cmdlet

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsLifecycle.Start, "Foo")]
public class StartFooCommand : PSCmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true)]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        // Perform various Foo-related activities...

        Object pipelineObject = GetTheObjectPassedInFromThePipeline();

        WriteObject(pipelineObject);
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to this in my script

```
# $foo would be some return value from another cmdlet
$foo = New-Object PSObject -prop @{ Name = "Frank"; Bar = "Baz" }
$foo | Get-Foo | Use-Foo
#    ^         ^ Here I want to pass the original $foo object to the next cmdlet
#    L Name gets bound from my object to my property
```

Comment: Post some relevant code that demonstrates your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to include another parameter which has the ValueFromPipeline=$true attribute.

Comment: Brilliant! It never even occurred to me that the pipeline object itself would bind to one parameters in addition to its properties binding to other parameters.

Comment: I don't usually do it that way but it does work.  :-)

Comment: I doubt many people do. I'm sure this is all a terrible idea, but I'm not experienced enough with PS to recognize what will surely bite me later ;)

Comment: It's not a terrible idea, I don't think, but I haven't ever really needed to do it.  Several built-in commands allow the output of the original object via a -Passthru switch, but doing that with only ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName would be really hard.